# JavaScript Modules, Closures and Scope

Tags: javascript, module, scope, amd, commonjs

I am using the following closure pattern to modularise my code:

```
(function(root) {
  // MODULE CODE HERE

  if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) { // CommonJS 
    /* var dependencies = require(...) */
    module.exports = myModule;
  } else if (typeof define !== 'undefined' && define.amd) { // AMD
    /* var dependencies...; */
    define([/* dependencies */], function(/* dependencies */) {
      /* Assign closure level vars to respective arguments */
      return myModule;
    });
  } else {
    // Dependencies??
    root.myModule = myModule;
  }
})(this);
```

i.e., We use feature detection to support CommonJS modules (e.g., node.js), AMD or basic global namespace instantiation.

This works fine in node.js; <strike>I haven't tested the AMD pattern yet, as I'm still reading up on it</strike> (See Edit 2: AMD exhibits the exact same effect); but it fails in the browser *if* the module has any dependencies. That is, say, if `myModule` references something that is defined in a different module: For example, say if I had `super.js` and `child.js` with respective module definitions, as above, where `super.js` creates a function called `root.super` (`root === window` in the browser), if `child.js` tries to do `super()`, I will get something like `super is not a function`.

What's going on here?

To try to fix it, I changed the order in which `super.js` and `child.js` are loaded in `<script>` elements: No luck. Then I tried forcing `child.js` to load when the document is ready, using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getScript('child.js', function() {
    // Do stuff with child, which calls super
  });
});
```

...again, same problem. However, in both cases, if I enter the console, `super` is available and defined as I'm expecting.

Why is `super` in `child.js` presumably from a different (i.e., not the global) scope?

---

I should add, if I remove the dependency injection bit in the CommonJS export, it fails in node.js with the same error (if there are any dependants).

---

**EDIT** @Amberlamps' answer solved the problem, but it didn't answer the question as to why this occurs. My module pattern is now:

```
(function(root) {
  // MODULE CODE HERE

  if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) { // CommonJS 
    /* var dependencies = require(...) */
    module.exports = myModule;
  } else if (typeof define !== 'undefined' && define.amd) { // AMD
    /* var dependencies...; */
    define([/* dependencies */], function(/* dependencies */) {
      /* Assign closure level vars to respective arguments */
      return myModule;
    });
  } else {
    if (root.hasOwnProperty(/* dependencies */)) {
      /* var dependencies = root... */
      root.myModule = myModule;
    }
  }
})(this);
```

This keeps dependants with a common name, across environments. However, the question remains: Why is the global object not available within the closure's scope?

---

**EDIT 2** I've been experimenting with RequireJS and AMD and have corrected my code, above, so that the AMDs work. Exactly the same thing happens in this case, too: You have to explicitly assign the global object to a variable within the closure for it to be available within said closure...

Comment: Is `this` the `window` object?

Comment: @Amberlamps, I assume you're talking about where `this` is aliased to `root`. In a browser `this` refers to `window`, but on a server (node.js) `this` refers to `global`. Using the alias to `root` allows a module to be used on both client and server side.

Comment: @zzzzBov: I know, but `this` could be anything, if the IIFE is not in the global scope.

Comment: @topic I cannot quite wrap my mind around your problem as I do not see any errors.

Comment: @Amberlamps, it is implied to be within the global scope as `this` is being aliased to `root`, and no wrapping code is provided.

Comment: @zzzzBov: I am just trying to trouble shoot. You will never know...

Comment: Why are you so sure "this/root" gets actual "window" reference on AMD loaders? There is absolutely no guarantee of that in the AMD spec. The whole module can be wrapped into another closure where "global" is actually a *local* synthetic object and evaled. If you need 'window' ask for it by name. By the way, this way deep into edits the question bacomes unclear. Could you give actual source of what does not work?

Answer (score 2):

This pattern works just fine. If you actually tested it with a function called `super` and calling it via `super()`, you might ran into an error, because `super` is a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words). Following code works fine:

```
(function(root) {

    root.super = function() {

        console.log("hello");

    };

}) (window);

(function(root) {

    root.super();

}) (window);
```

You can call your function using `window.super()`. `super()` however will result in an error.

Comment: `super` and `child` were the first semantic examples I came up with, I actually used different names... Anyway, thank you for this :) However, why is it the case? Why is the global name not available in the closure's scope?